# Quartz Scheduler failed to initialize

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Getting these errors:

```
2018-01-22 18:00:59,797 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 79] ERROR org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener - Quartz Scheduler failed to initialize: org.quartz.SchedulerException: SchedulerPlugin class 'org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin' could not be instantiated. [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin by any known loaders.]
2018-01-22 18:00:59,797 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 79] ERROR stderr - org.quartz.SchedulerException: SchedulerPlugin class 'org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin' could not be instantiated. [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin by any known loaders.]
2018-01-22 18:00:59,805 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 79] ERROR stderr - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin by any known loaders.
2018-01-22 18:00:59,805 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 79] ERROR stderr - Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/quartz/plugins/xml/XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin (Module "deployment.Reports.ear:main" from Service Module Loader)
2018-01-22 18:00:59,806 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 79] ERROR stderr - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/jobs/FileScanListener
2018-01-22 18:00:59,807 [ServerService Thread Pool -- 79] ERROR stderr - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.jobs.FileScanListener from [Module "deployment.Reports.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

quartz.properties file:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = Scheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QUARTZ.QRTZ_
#org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.jndiURL=java:QuartzDataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = quartz-jobs-xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 0
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction =false
```

My `quartz-jobs.xml` file is in the same directory as my `quartz.properties.xml` file. I tried playing around with that path a little. But I think the errors are just saying it can't instantiate my jobs.

Comment: take a look at http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/8582.page to see if it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to add a new quartz library to my build to include the `XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin` that I reference in my `quartz.properties`.

In my root `build.gradle` I add this to my `ext.libraries` section:

```
quartz_jobs: 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:2.3.0'
```

Then in my web services `build.gradle` where I use quartz, I add the library to my `providedCompile` section:

```
libraries.quartz-jobs
```